Next.js + Prisma + SQLite: Build Doesn't Fetch New Database Data
I'm creating a Next.js app that uses SQLite and Prisma for data. I'm having a problem:
I build the app (using next build).
Then, I add new data to the database (SQLite).
When I run the built app, it only shows the data that existed before the build. The new data doesn't appear.
Basically, the built version of the app isn't fetching the latest data from the database.
i have tried every solution present on the internt

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
